# how to switch between carousel item using button or hyperlink in sencha touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, carousel

Is there a way that I can using a button or hyperlink to navigate from first carousel to the second carousel item and vice versa instead of using the indicator? Can someone give me a solution to fulfil this task? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`setActiveItem`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel-method-setActiveItem) on [`button's tap`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Button-event-tap) event.

```
tap: function() {
 ....
 carousel.setActiveItem(2); // Moves to the 3rd carousel item.
 ....
}
```

Comment: Also, carousel.next() or carousel.previous()